# I want to know 'd-vector' for speaker diarization

Tags: audio, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm, mfcc

When segmented speech audio was added to DNN model, I understood that the average value of the features extracted from the last hidden layer is 'd-vector'.
In that case, I want to know if the d-vector of the speaker can be extracted even if I put the voice of the speaker without learning.
By using this, when a segmented value of a voice file spoken by multiple people (using a mel-filterbank or MFCC) is put in, can we distinguish the speaker by clustering the extracted d-vector value as mentioned before?

Comment: To which model are you referring?

Comment: Hello @LukaszTracewski
I think I can extract d-vector, from speak classify DNN model such as LSTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. After you train the model, you can get the `d-vector` simply by forward-propagating the input vector through the network. Normally you look at the output (final layer) of the ANN, but you can equally retrieve values from penultimate (the `d-vector`) layer.
2. Yes, you can distinguish speakers with the `d-vector`, as it produces in a way a high-level embedding of the audio signal that will have unique features for different people. See e.g. this [paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41939.pdf).